# CSS @print page margins without titles

Tags: css, printing

I m trying to insert some margin in each page break but the margin inserts in the bottom of the last page , the url and the page number. I've tried many workarounds but none of them seems to work. There is no way to insert a margin without having them?

CSS

```
@media print {  

  @page {
    size: A4 ;
    margin: 5mm 0;  
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use `vh` as a height on the container of each page as a workaround maybe?

Comment: @MarcHjorth there is no effect. Actually, print css attributes accepts only actual units of measurement like mm, cm etc

Comment: I once used `vh` & `vw` as units for a print project so I highly doubt that

Comment: you used it body or in @page element?

Comment: I used it on a container on each page. Didn't use `@page`

Comment: And when you had a single container in two differents pages? I mean starting from page 1 and ends in page 2 middle??? What happened when the page breaked? did you have margin???

Comment: Added a number for each page like `page1, page2` and added the height to these classes. You can defined the height so that it fits to your margin. This way you don't need a margin, so to speak. This is just how I did it, can't help you further I'm sorry

Comment: @MarcHjorth You mean you manually created each page, or is there a way to assign the classes/numbers automatically?

Comment: I don't know how many pages you need to do this for. I just had to do it for 2 pages, so I could assign the two pages different classes, because I always knew there was 2 pages only.